# Mounted external drive through fstab, permission denied even with sudo

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, fstab, external-hdd

I followed https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md and mounted my external seagate driver like this:

```
PARTUUID=225d3878-01  /media/external ntfs    defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

I tried `UUID=...` but it wouldn't work, it always gave me boot errors, couldn't even access shell.

In this way I did, it boots, but when I go to `/media` and do `ls -la`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 May  7 18:52 external
```

external is marked green, like it were different from other things. I get Permission Denied when I try to write to it, even with sudo, but the permissions are `777`.

How to change these permissions to ones less permissive and make it writable by my user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use a Pi and I also attach a extern HDD.

To get it working with ntfs you need 2 other tools:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g fuse
```

and then you can mount your drive with
-t ntfs-3g #is needed to get read write access to ntfs drives
-o #are some options
-uid=1000 #is the id of my main user you can also use names
-gid=100 #group id of users to make it simple 
-then we need a source my usb-stick with ntfs is located at SDC and the parition is SDC1
-the last point is the destination and I want it into /mnt/usbstick

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=100 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb-stick
```

So the answer to your Qestion is NTFS-3G instead of NTFS.

If this is working you can also use it in your fstab.

Hint: NTFS-3G will always set access level to 777 so no wory if the folder is green :-)

br
chris

br chris